# What is the equivalent of chmod 777?

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to replace `notepad.exe` with `notepad2.exe`, but I'm getting UAC permission issues when I try to open a file with the replacement `notepad2.exe`.  I have to open `notepad2.exe` as admin.

How can I perform a Windows 7 equivalent of the linux `chmod 777` on the file?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using cacls you can do this same type thing, example.

```
cacls myfile.txt /g everyone:f
```

Comment: Note that explicit *deny* entries can override this.

Comment: Good point, replacing the /g with /p will take care of this.

Comment: Please note that from Windows 7 onwards cacls is considered deprecated by Microsoft and icacls should be used instead.

Comment: What is `cacls`? -1 for not giving any infos or providing a link to the page.

Answer (score 22):

Roughly:

```
icacls notepad.exe /grant Everyone:F
```

Note that this isn't exactly the same as *deny* ACL entries override *allow* entries, so if there are any *deny* ones you may need to remove them.

Generally, I honestly have to question the motives of what you are attempting to do. There should never be a reason to replace core operating system files with other ones.

You can easily associate text files with Notepad2 without replacing `notepad.exe` which should be the preferred way of dealing with this.

Comment: This still works great in Windows 10. At risk of stating the obvious, make sure you're logged in as a user with the required privileges (usually owner or admin). Easiest method is simply starting an admin console, usage at your own risk. I wouldn't recommend replacing core system files, but every once in a while your OS will decide you're not allowed access to a folder you really want access to. This command works on folders as well.

Answer (score 4):

This may work, tailor your command line as needed:

Step 1 - Open cmd window with admin privileges

Step 2 - to take ownership of contents of "picts" directory

```
     takeown /f C:\picts\* /r
```

Step 3 - to change permissions to "everyone" of contents of "picts" directory

```
     icacls C:\picts /grant Everyone:F /t
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change the permissions from the command line via [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/windows-change-access-permissions-from-the-command-line.html) information, although I personally find that the GUI permission controls are pretty easy to understand.

You can use it as follows:

```
CACLS files /e /p {USERNAME}:{PERMISSION}
```

Where:

- /p : Set new permission
- /e : Edit
  permission and kept old permission as
  it is i.e. edit ACL instead of
  replacing it.
- {USERNAME} : Name of
  user
- {PERMISSION} : Permission can
  be: R - Read W - Write C - Change
  (write) F - Full control

Comment: `CACLS` is deprecated. Microsoft recommends using `ICACLS` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could install a free Windows terminal program like [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download.html). When you open it you will see it gives you access to your local Windows pc directories but emulates a Linux command-line-interface, offering several Linux commands based on Cygwin such as `chmod`.

I'm sure there are also other tabbed Windows terminal programs out there that emulate a Linux CLI. I just currently use MobaXterm. I find it useful to keep several tabs going while using the same commands across each: one for my remote Linux server, one for a VirtualBox Linux server, and one for my local Windows pc.