# Renaming a file on mapped WebDAV drive does not work with Windows client, but with NetDrive or WebDrive

Tags: windows, windows-8, webdav

When I map a network drive to [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com) WebDAV via:

```
net use a: "https://myserver/alfresco/webdav/Sites/" /User:admin admin
```

I can execute operations like creating, deleting, copying a file, but I **cannot rename** a file. Renaming results in an error "**A device attached to the system is not functioning.**":

```
> rename test.docx test2.docx
A device attached to the system is not functioning.
(Ein an das System angeschlossenes Gerät funktioniert nicht.)
```

The user has sufficient permissions.
When mapping the WebDAV folder via [NetDrive](http://netdrive.net/) or [MapDrive](http://www.southrivertech.com/) instead of using Windows/"net use", it works fine.
Seems like a problem with the embedded WebDAV client in Windows.

There are not many files in the folder, in which I want to rename the file. Only 10 or so.

I would understand somehow if it would be a general issue and I would not be able to connect at all, but why does only the renaming command fail? Does anybody have experienced this issue and any idea how to solve it?

Environment:

- Client: Windows 8.1
- Server (Alfresco/WebDAV): Windows 2012 RC2 Server

**=== Update: ===**

I tried the same on my local Alfresco instance

- Client: Windows 8.1
- Server (Alfresco/WebDAV): Windows 8.1

and here, **renaming** works fine. Seems to be an issue with the Windows 2012 Server configuration, but I am not sure where to look at.
I already compared the Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc: Configuration -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options), but did not find any significant differences.

Comment: A bit related, but compared to that thread, I do not see anything in the Alfresco log on the server-side. https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/configuration/webdav-rename-moving-failure#comment-159507

Answer (score 0):

I have not enough reputation to comment, so I'm writing an answer instead...

My thought is, that your CHMOD is incorrect. I've just reproduced that using my owncloud. If I set the CHMOD to 555 I will get the same error as described by you. However when I change it to 644 (as it's supposed to be) I have no issues at all.

I don't think that it's an issue with the embedded WebDAV Client of Windows, as it's working for me on two different machines using Windows 7 and Windows 10.

But I can't really tell you why it's working with NetDrive / MapDrive, though.. :)

Anyway, I would suggest you to check your CHMOD and maybe set it to 755 on folders and 644 to files.

Comment: The server is a Windows server, not Linux. Therefore I tried the Windows equivalent for CHMOD, but it does not work.
I tried "cacls test.txt /g everyone:f" and "icacls test.txt /grant Everyone:F" as per 
http://superuser.com/questions/163049/what-is-the-equivalent-of-chmod-777, but it does not work. First command sys, CACLS only works on NTFS-Filesystems, and the second also throws an error.

Comment: Also, going into the file properties of a file on WebDAV drive, it does not show any security tab/settings; I assume that the permissions should be handled by the security layer of the WebDAV server (Alfresco in my case).

Comment: Well I'm sorry but I have no experience with Alfresco, I just wanted to check how it's working on my server and I was able to reproduce it by changing the CHMOD. But if your access rights are good, I might be wrong about my thought - sorry :(