# How do I specify chmod 744 in Powershell?

Tags: permissions, powershell, file-permissions

I know that I can use icacls to specify the permission on the file, and from [What is the equivalent of chmod 777?](https://superuser.com/questions/163049/what-is-the-equivalent-of-chmod-777), I can use

```
icacls myfile.txt /grant Everyone:F
```

But how do I set an equivalent for chmod 744? I think I can use `/grant:____:R` for just read access, but I'm not sure how to specify the owners and the group permissions as simply as with chmod. When I try this:

```
icacls myfile.txt /grant Owner:F Group:R Everyone:R
```

I receive an error, "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done." I'm probably missing something obvious, any ideas?

When I try:

```
icacls myfile.txt /grant Administrator:F /grant:r Users:R
```

I take a look at the file in Explorer and it has given Administrator "Special Permissions" (rather than Full Control) and gives Users "Read & execute, Read, and Special Permissions."

Comment: If you specifically want 744, you might as well skip group permissions (not applicable on Windows anyway) altogether because they’re already covered with “Everyone” permissions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a shot and see if this does what you're trying to accomplish. I always run these explicitly so one for setting the `Owner`, one for `Full Control`, one for `Read-only`, and one for `Read and Execute`.

This way you can do it for a specific file and for a specific user or group where applicable. Just plug in your file names, etc.

***Sample ICACLS commands to set owner, grant full control, read-only, and read plus execute access***
*(You may need to run the command prompt as administrator with these commands)*

```
::Set Owner of a specific file
ICACLS "D:\test\test.txt" /setowner "administrator"

::Grant Full Control
ICACLS "D:\test\test.txt" /grant:r "administrator:(F)" /C

::Grant Read and Execute Access of a specific file
ICACLS "D:\test\test.txt" /grant:r "users:(RX)" /C

::Grant Read-only Access of a specific file
ICACLS "D:\test\test.txt" /grant:r "users:(R)" /C
```