# passwordless ssh from linux to windows

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin

[image][image]

I am trying to login to Windows without password from a Linux server. I have already installed OpenSSH from GitHub and I'm able to do `scp` and `ssh`. I tried copying the `authorized_keys` to the Windows location. But it's still not working.
The functionality should be no password prompt for running ssh or scp from linux environment to login/show windows directory.

I tried below commands:

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh edh_win@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'

ssh edh_win@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

But getting error not able to understand `cat` and `chmod`.

Updating the errors

```
'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Do I need to install cygwin? If yes, please help with the implementation.

Any assistance is appreciated. Below is an image of the error.

[image: image of the error]

Comment: Have you googled cygwin ssh server install? The steps are install cygwin's sshd server, run the config, login. I'm not going to do this for you.

Comment: Let me try installing the same

Comment: @ djsmiley2k   Still facing the same.Even though installed the cygwin. Attaching the screenshots in question.Dont know what I am missing here

Comment: Just an FYI, [`type`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/type) is the Windows equivalent of `cat` and [`icacls`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls) is the equivalent of `chmod`

Answer (score 15):

Steps to establish passwordless SSH between Linux ⬌ Windows:

**Note:**

- Open a PowerShell console with Administrator privileges and execute all the commands mentioned below in that console only
- Depending on install path, add `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH` or `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH` to the System `Path`

---

## Windows Server 2019:

- Ensure the system is up to date via Windows Update
- Ensure OpenSSH features are installed:

  - *Apps & Features* > *Manage Optional Features*
  - *OpenSSH Server* and *OpenSSH Client* should be listed, if they are not: *Add a Feature*

---

## Windows Server 2012 and 2016:

1. Download [OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) (`OpenSSH-Win64.zip`)
2. Extract the contents to `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH` and enter directory
3. Follow steps 4 - 6 mentioned in the [Install Wiki](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH):

   ```powershell
   # In an elevated Powershell console, run the following:
     powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File install-sshd.ps1

   # Open the firewall for sshd.exe to allow inbound SSH connections
     New-NetFirewallRule -Name sshd -DisplayName 'OpenSSH Server (sshd)' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -LocalPort 22

   # Start sshd (this will automatically generate host keys under %programdata%\ssh if they don't already exist)
     net start sshd ; net start ssh-agent
   ```

---

### Common Steps for Windows Server 2012/2016/2019:

1. Execute the following, which should show the status as `Running` for both services:

   ```powershell
   Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic

   Set-Service sshd -StartupType Automatic

   Get-Service -Name ssh-agent,sshd
   ```

   **If not running:** open *Services* and start `OpenSSH Server` and `OpenSSH Authentication Agent`
2. For public-private key pair generation, issue `ssh-keygen` and follow the prompts
3. Create `C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys`:

   ```powershell
   New-Item -ItemType file "C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys"
   ```
4. Append `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to `C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys`

   - If `id_rsa.pub` does not exist on Linux, generate via: `ssh-keygen`
5. Append `C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

   - If `authorized_keys` does not exist:

     ```powershell
     touch "/root/.ssh/authorized_keys"
     ```
6. For permission settings:

   ```powershell
   icacls "C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys" /remove "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users"

   icacls "C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys" /inheritance:r

   Restart-Service -Name sshd, ssh-agent -Force
   ```

---

**Relevant locations on Windows host:**

- `C:\Windows\Sytem32\OpenSSH\`
- `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\`
- `C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh\`
- `C:\ProgramData\ssh\`

---

**References:**

- Microsoft Docs: [OpenSSH Key Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement)
- Win32-OpenSSH Github: [Install Wiki](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH)
- Win32-OpenSSH Github: [Logging Facilities](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Logging-Facilities)

Comment: This guide is awesome, but it has one flaw: What happens if the user is not admin on windows? I mean, a different user than root in linux and not "Administrator" on windows?

Comment: This answer should be accepted as its perfectly working

Answer (score 1):

The errors say it all.

More or less, your ssh server provides... well, an ssh server. It dosen't have the 'unix' style or linux coreutils you're trying to run by default.

While swapping this ssh server for cygwin might help - what you literally need to do is understand what you're doing and not presume linux commands will work.

You can probably get cat on windows - through various native packages of it like the [ones bundled with git](http://git-scm.com/download/win) or [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow)

The permissions model probably works differently so you need to do it with native tools.

It needs some reading but [this suggests](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/ssh.exe-examples) "only System, Administrators and owner can have access"- and [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1002883/how-do-i-specify-chmod-744-in-powershell) suggests you can use `ICACLS` to set the appropriate permissions.

The takeaway is - well you got to understand your tools and realise that you're not going to find the same environment everywhere.