# SSH into device through WSL when connected via hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hotspot

I have connected my Raspberry Pi to Windows computer's hotspot network. I cannot connect the Pi to the Wi-Fi network at my university because they only allow one device at a time (so I'll lose internet on my laptop if I connect the Pi to the WAP).

From PowerShell, if I type `ssh npi` (`npi` being the hostname of the Pi), it works as expected. However on WSL (Debian), it just seems to hang/wait for a long time and nothing happens.

How do I connect to my Pi via WSL when it's connected to my computer's hotspot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting scenario.  I'm going to take an educated guess here, since recreating this on my end would be a bit too time consuming.  But keep in mind that I haven't had a chance to test this (*however, for future readers, the OP has confirmed that it works via comments*).

The problem seems to be that:

- The Windows host has a connection to the Internet through the Wi-fi adapter to your university's network.
- That connection is shared to WSL2 using a Hyper-V switch (that we really don't have much control over).
- That connection is also shared (separately) with the RPi through the Windows hotspot feature.
- As a result, the WSL2 Debian distribution and the RPi are on two separate networks that have no route between them.

If you just need `ssh` access, then my proposal would be to use the Windows OpenSSH server as a jumphost.  You'll likely need to [install it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui) and configure the firewall rules (also covered in that doc).

Then, from Debian, you can:

```
ssh <windows_username>@$(hostname).local
```

The `$(hostname).local` uses [mDNS to connect to the Windows host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407064/11810933).  From there, you can "jump" to your Pi with `ssh npi`.

You can also shortcut it a bit and just specify the jumphost directly from Debian with something like:

```
ssh -A -J <windows_user>@$(hostname).local <npi_username>@npi
```

As you noted in the comments (for other readers), you can also simplify this further with a `~/.ssh/config` file as documented [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host#Static_jump_host_list).  You'll need to hardcode the Windows hostname, in that case, with the output of `echo $(hostname).local`.

With a `config` in place, you can be back to simply:

```
ssh npi
```

##### Other services

If you need to access other services on the RPi from WSL2/Debian, then you can still use SSH tunneling to forward the required ports between the two.

##### Public-private key authentication.

In short, add the public key of the WSL system to your Windows system using [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1507624/1324313).

Following that, add your WSL public key to the Raspberry Pi. You can again "jump", using the following command (executed form WSL):

```bash
ssh-copy-id -o ProxyJump=<windows_username>@<windows_hostname>.local <Pi-username>@<Pi-hostname>
```

Comment: This is working, thank you! I'm editing your answer with additional steps needed to setup public/private-key authentication for SSH.

Comment: `GatewayPorts yes` config was not required. Probably set by default

Comment: Helpful article for configuring SSH aliases, making it faster to jump: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host#Static_jump_host_list

Comment: @eccentricOrange Good to hear - And thanks for working through it and updating the things I got wrong.  I think I did pretty good going mostly from memory, but it definitely needed some tweaks ;-)

Comment: Your answer certainly pointed me in the right direction, General Kenobi