# How do I specify chmod 744 in Windows Powershell recursively?

Tags: powershell, permissions, chmod

Was going to comment on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1002883/how-do-i-specify-chmod-744-in-powershell) but I do not have the rep.

Is there a way to do this recursively?

I would like to give all privileges to any administrator user.

Nothing I do in the windows GUI seems to stick.

Edit 1: I had installed a Go program called Sabaki in another drive (D:). This was the folder I was trying to move. Uninstall got rid of it. The other folders in the folder that Sabaki was in were made by me and I had no problems moving or deleting them. So I have avoided the whole issue.

Currently my vision is very poor. I may try those experiments in the power shell when it gets better.

Comment: What have you done that didn't stick?

Comment: I wrote the answer to that question, what's up?? A good starting point might be to go to cmd and then run `ICACLS /?` to see a list of options. You can run `ICACLS` in PowerShell just fine. Let me know though.

Comment: @harrymc usin the propertiesturning off the read only and security allow all.

Comment: @Vomit  thanks, i may try that when my vision improves. found a workaround as the folder i had the problem with was an installation of a program.

Comment: There's no way that these permissions won't stick, unless some program is actively modifying them.

Comment: I assume you are installing to a different program files folder than the "C" drive, correct?

Comment: @Vomit Please see Edit 1. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad you worked around it by uninstalling successfully and manually deleting any saved user data on the "D" drive. I'm glad you were able to avoid it entirely and resolve your issue. Installing off core/root "C" partition in Windows can act funny if the NTFS permissions are not set like they are on the correlated `C:\Program Files` directories and such. I don't think I have anything existing where I've had to map that out programmatically. Maybe here: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2061618-mirroring-permissions-between-two-drives with `C:\Program Files` & `D:\Program Files`